# Problems with JPackage due to different path structure between Windows and Linux

Tags: java, linux, java-14, jpackage

On Windows I have just converted my application installer from **Izpack** to **JPackage** and because of the structure created by JPackage I had to make some code changes to allow my application to find various config files, basically they are copied from **app** folder to **C:\Users\Username\Appdata....** on first start (but bit more complicated than that).

I am now using JPackage on Linux, and the application copies config files from app to $HOME/.appname. However whereas on Windows **app** is a subfolder relative to launcher with Linux its now in **../lib/app** so the code doesnt work

So I have to make some linux specific changes, but it got me wondering am I doing something very wrong here in order for me to have to make these changes ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to load configuration files is using the classloader: the files are packaged in a jar along with the rest of your application and you load them as a stream, not as a file:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    InputStream stream = YourApplication.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/conf.properties");
    properties.load(stream);
```

The path (example) `/resources/conf.properties` is relative the .jar file where the file is bundled, so it does no depend on the installation folder.

The above example assumes that you're using a Properties file but this works for any resource you can load as a stream.

Comment: But users sometimes need to edit them, so storing in a jar is not a solution. I have it working as it is, but still wondering if my approach is wrong or if Oracle have made a bad choice here.

Comment: Ah ok, if these are editable by the user I guess you have to deal with the difference between platforms. But if you're asking about the initial copy of the file then the answer is valid: you should be loading the default file from a .jar and saving it as a file

Comment: @PaulTaylor Wouldn't it be more appropriate to have the default configuration embedded (as mentioned by Guillaume) and then copy it to a _user location_ (e.g. user home, platform-specific app data location, etc.) as needed? Copying the files into the installation location seems problematic, if only because you may or may not have write access in that location. Anyway, you may be able to find something in [Packaging Tool's User Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/preface.html#GUID-C8F52DC6-0750-497D-9DAB-2F88E10787BE).

Comment: You may have a point but let me explain further,. On first run of program I do copy config files to a user location, but Im copying files from the installation location rather than from a jar. My problem was the code that copies to user location has to account for the difference in locations when doing that initial copy. If the config was in a jar file instead I would still have the issue that the location was different but I suppose if the jar was on the classpath then I wouldn't have to worry about it, but simpler to just copy some files over.

Comment: The point is that when loading a file from a jar, you don't need to know the location of the jar, so you don't need to know the installation location.